# Thread-safe error handling in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

Is there a way to get thread-safe error handling, short of putting a mutex around the entire API call? The error code and string don't appear to be thread local, and [the docs](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/errcode.html) appear to suggest using a mutex to fix this. It's hard to believe that there isn't a better way to do this, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insofar as I'm aware, no, there is no other way.

Fwiw, transaction isolation is done, in SQLite, through good old file locking.